# Change the structure of the array (make nested arrays in the array)

Tags: php

I have an array and I don’t know how to change it to the structure I need:
My array:

```
array (
  "1536" => "12",
  "1695" => "Korea",
  "1904" => "10/7",
  "1905" => "",
  "1906" => null,
  "1907" => "1.1",
  "1906.1" => "H1",
  "1906.2" => "H35",
  "1905.1" => "15"
)
```

I need to cast this array to this form (remove the tenths of the numbers, and paste the values of the same numbers into the array):

```
array (
  "1536" => "12",
  "1695" => "Korea",
  "1904" => "10/7",
  "1905" => array("", "15"),
  "1906" => array(null, "H1", "H35"),
  "1907" => "1.1"
)
```

Comment: Jay Blanchard, this is not a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe a `foreach` with index parsing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an iteration over the array using [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). In every cycle of the iteration check weather the key already exist in the `$res` array. If exist then create array merging with old value and assign to the same key. If not key already exist then assign the `$val` to the `$res` array.

```
$data = array("1536" => "12","1695" => "Korea","1904" => "10/7","1905" => "", "1906" => null,"1907" => "1.1","1906.1" => "H1","1906.2" => "H35","1905.1" => "15");

$res = array();
array_walk($data, function($val, $key) use(&$res) {
    $key = intval($key);
    if (array_key_exists($key, $res)) {
        $res[$key] = is_array($res[$key]) ? array_merge($res[$key], [$val]) : array_merge([$res[$key]], [$val]);
    } else {
        $res[$key] = $val;
    }
});

print_r($res);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/ActDG).